# How does one format a letter in the Memoir document class for LaTeX?

Tags: latex, typesetting, letter, memoir

If you have a traditional letter with content like-so.

```
From Someone
50 Example Drive
Random City, ZIP
Country
Tel: 444-555-6666

July 30, 2009

To Somebody
51 Example Drive
Random City, ZIP
Country
Tel: 444-555-7777


Dear Somebody:

Get off my lawn!

Sincerely yours,


Someone
```

How can one create such a letter using the LaTeX Memoir class.

In other words, using the Letter class the canon is:

```
\documentclass{letter}

    \signature{Your name}
    \address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
    \begin{document}

        \begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
        \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

        \dots

        \closing{Yours Faithfully,}
        \ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
        \encl{Enclosures.}

    \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

How would one achieve similar or the same formatting using the Memoir class?

Thank you & cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that Memoir is set up for a letter class out of the box. You might want to consider using scrlttr2 in the KOMA-Script package. Here is an [example](http://gpl.coulmann.de/scrlttr2.html) of its use.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the answer you are seeking, but the Memoir manual is great-- I would consult it first.

Comment: I've read the excellent manual through, but there's no clear answer. I'd hoped that someone had already done the work ... :)

Comment: why not just use the letter class?

Comment: @mica: the letter class has broken section headings (i.e. you end up with orphans). The memoir class does not suffer from that issue.

Comment: @Brian: the letter class probably doesn't have a section heading... because its a letter... see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters

Comment: @Mica: That's a problem, too, then. :o)

Comment: you could always "fake" a section... set a counter for a new deceleration, give it some styling, etc.